# Using array data to drill a query

Tags: coldfusion

I am learning about arrays and structs, and putting together a shopping cart as a project. I am currently creating a recently viewed products module for the cart. When a user views a product i collect the product id into an array,

[image: product array]
What is the best way to use this info to query my database, my query would be

```
<cfquery name="getRecent" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT uid_product,txt_product_name
FROM tbl_products
</cfquery>
```

I thought of outputting the array as a list and using the IN operator, but not sure if that is the right way of doing it, seems a bit cumbersome? Can I use a query of queries using the array data? If so any pointers?

Comment: Why do you need to have an array of structs? Will these structs hold other information as well or is it just the productID you want to track?

Comment: it will just be the product id so i can query the products table. Am i over complicating? Should i just hold the id's in a list 1,2,34 etc?

Comment: Hi, yes, I've answered below. No point in over-complicating things with structs and arrays if a simple list will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just maintain a list of productIDs then you don't need to use arrays or structs, you can just store them as a simple list and query them as follows:

```
<cfset recentProducts = "4,5" />

<cfquery name="getRecent" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT uid_product,txt_product_name
    FROM tbl_products
    where productID IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#recentProducts#" list="true" />)
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thanks Barry, complicate is my middle name! The list route is a far easier way!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, unless you're going to put additional things into the struct, I'd say having a struct just to hold ProductID seems excessive.  I'd just have the Array with the productID as each  element, no struct.

So your array is structured like:

```
[
  {  ProductID= 4 },
  {  ProductID= 5 },
  ...
]
```

I'd suggest you just do:

```
[4,5]
```

This will make the next step easier.  Right now I'd say you have to loop over your array, adding each productID into a list that you can then use in your query.  Then modify your original query to use that list (remember and use cfqueryparam).

```
<cfset lstIDs = "">
<cfloop index="productStruct" array="#productsArray#">
  <cfset lstIDs = listAppend(lstIDs, productStruct.ProductID)>
</cfloop>

<cfquery name="getRecent" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT uid_product,txt_product_name
FROM tbl_products
WHERE productID IN <cfqueryparam value="#lstIDs#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" list="yes">
</cfquery>
```

Or, if you simplify your array, just do ArrayToList to achieve the same thing.

```
<cfquery name="getRecent" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT uid_product,txt_product_name
FROM tbl_products
WHERE productID IN <cfqueryparam value="#ArrayToList(productsArray)#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" list="yes">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: thanks, the list route is obviously the best route to go down, bot yours and Barry's answers are correct, how do i show that, sorry still new to this site!

Comment: @Jason - you can only mark 1 as being correct, but you can upvote (by clicking on the up arrow) the other answer to show that it was also useful.

Comment: PS: in ColdFusion, Array functions are more efficient than list functions.  For most simple uses this won't matter, but if performance of your CFML is important, you might want to use an array instead of a list.